# User-defined functions in Database (PostgreSQL)

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, stored-procedures

Say I have defined the data-structure:

```
Users(u_id, name);
```

As well as a stored-procedure / function to get a full profile of the user, given the `u_id`:

```
getUserProfile(u_id) RETURNS (u_id, firstname, lastname, age);
```

Now, I want to have a way to easily retrieve all users, *say under the age of 20*.
What would be the appropriate component to build on top of this, so that I could call something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_profiles as UP
WHERE UP.age < '20'
```

Comment: Essential information is missing. Where do `firstname, lastname, age` come from? What is a "data-structure" supposed to be? The function `getUserProfile()` is obviously specialized in returning the details for one user. You need to query the source table.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Actually, the `getUserProfile()` function executes some procedural-language function, in fact PL/Java. But, what I really like is to have some way of querying user-profiles, similar to if it was a data-set. I.e. Finding all my users who are of a particular age?

Comment: @Larry: if you define your `getUserProfile()` function as `returns table` you can use it like a view: `select * from getUserProfile() where age < 20` of course in that case you would not pass a u_id to it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know what you’re saying, although in this case, I cannot change this function. It is actually a function built on a few sub-functions, and this really is the system design. So assuming, this is what I need to work with, how could I manage to achieve what I want, i.e. like where I can make queries on the properties of my users.

Comment: @Larry: do you have a table that stores all the users (especially the user id)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, the USER table, just stores (u_id, name), but in order to get further details, I need to use the function.

Comment: @Larry: what exactly is the return type of the function `getUserProfile()`? Is that a custom data type with three attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming getUserProfile() returns a custom data type with the mentioned columns, you can do the following:

```
SELECT (prof).u_id, 
       (prof).firstname, 
       (prof).lastname, 
       (prof).age
FROM (
  SELECT getUserProfile(u_id) as prof
  FROM users
) t
WHERE (prof).age < 20
```

Note that the **column** prof needs to be enclosed in brackets, otherwise the parser will think it's a table reference.

You can wrap the whole thing into a view (apparently without the WHERE condition) to make things easier.

Comment: Thanks, very much, this is good. And yes, the function would return a custom data-type similar to what you have. Another thing, what is t, just something arbitrary?

Comment: @Larry: t is an alias for the derived table ("sub-select"). It is required by Postgres. You could also use `user_profile` instead

Comment: I just had a further question about this? How exactly does the function getUserProfile(u_id) know to take the u_id from the Table Users? Furthermore, what I mean is, could I have something like getUserProfile(u_id, a_id, b_id), where also the entity Users is defined with schema [u_id, a_id, b_id, name]. Could this still work, or what tweaks would be necessary?

Comment: @Larry: as the select is using `from users` the reference to `u_id` must be from the table `users`. And yes you can extend the function `getUserProfile()` to accept more parameters.

Comment: Ok, so does this mean I need to name my function parameters so that they match, or it will just take the params in the order that it selects from Users?

Comment: @Larry: the parameter name is only there for convenience inside your function. You could name them tom, dick and harry if you want. You should read the chapter in the PostgreSQL manual regarding PL/pgSQL and functions in general. It does explain all those concepts.

Comment: Thanks, I totally understand things now. Just another question, if say in the first-select I also want to return attributes that are not in the getProfile function, but are contained in the User-entity. For example, like I mentioned above, say User has other attributes such as [a_id, b_id], etc. Then how could I also return these values in the first-select? Perhaps you could augment this to your answer (without removing the original answer). Would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you need another stored-procedure / function  to get the users under the age of 20 and for each user this first proc or function returns, you can call the second.

Or you can do everything in one structure. Create a procedure that returns users' information and that accept another parameter called age and then you return a result set instead of only one user.